# Using GitLab, projects are missing from the API list

Tags: gitlab

I use the GitLab API to fetch a list of the projects I have access to (URL `/api/v3/projects/all?private_token=xxx`), but there are 6-7 projects that are not included in the list for some reason.

EDIT: My user is an administrator, and I want to list *all* projects like the `/projects/all` URL indicates.

I have access to the projects just fine using git itself and the GitLab web interface. Any suggestions why the projects wouldn't be shown in the list from the API?

All the projects missing are newer than the others. I have tried refreshing my API token; no change.

Versions:

```
GitLab        6.4.3
GitLab Shell  1.8.0
GitLab API    v3
Ruby          2.0.0p353
Rails         4.0.2
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I just tested this and it looks like the GitLab API response is using pagination. According to the documentation (http://api.gitlab.org), the default number of results per page is set to 20 and the starting page is 1.

To adjust the maximum results per page, you need to use the `per_page` variable in the HTTP request line. You can change the page number by using `page` as well, if you have more repositories than the maximum value of `per_page`. You can specify a maximum `per_page` value of 100.

For example, you request may look like:

```
https://git.example.com/api/v3/projects/all?page=1&per_page=100&private_token=abc123
```

The `page` and `per_page` variables are not required as they have default values, so you do not need to include either if you don't want to.

Hopefully this solves your problem.

Comment: It does indeed! I feel lazy and stupid now ;) Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problems, a lesson learned for myself too :)

Comment: Is there any way to return more than 100? My result of user activity is far more than 100 but the api only returns the max of 100.

Comment: From looking at the API documentation, it looks like the maximum `per_page` value allowed is `100`. Refer: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/README.html#pagination

Answer (score 0):

yes, it works with pagination you need to change the "page" parameter value and call multiple times as follows.

https://gitlab.example.com/api/v3/projects/all?page=1&per_page=100&private_token=some_token

https://gitlab.example.com/api/v3/projects/all?page=2&per_page=100&private_token=some_token

Answer (score -2):

If you aren't sure about number of pages use it as below:
`https://git.example.com/api/v3/projects/all?per_page=-1&private_token=some_token_key`

Comment: does not list all the projects... only give default 20 records

Comment: Same to me. Only shows default 20 items in the first page

Comment: doesn't do anything, only returns default 20